# How do I figure out what dependencies to install when I copy my Django app from one system to another?

Tags: django, python-3.x, centos, dependencies

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I want to write a script to help me easily migrate my application from my local machien (a Mac High Sierra) to a CentOS Linux instance.  I'm using a virtual environment in both places.  There are many things that need to be done here, but to keep the question specific, how do I determine on my remote machine (where I'm deploying my project to), what dependencies are lacking?  I'm using rsync to copy the files (minus the virtual environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the source system execute `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, then copy the `requiremnts.txt` to the target system and then on the target system install all the dependencies with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  Of course you will need to activate the virtual environments on both systems before execute the `pip` commands.

If you are using a source code management system like `git` it is a good idea to keep the `requirements.txt` up to date in your source code repository.

Comment: Getting an error on the remote server, "pip <command> [options], no such option: -r".  I'm looking at the man page, what is the "-r" option supposed to do?

Comment: oops that should be `pip install -r requirements.txt` I'll update my answer.